# SQL add a column of binary values based on values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL. Here is my question:
I get two temporary tables:

[image: Table 1]
[image: Table 2]

I want to add a new column to the first table to see if employee's score meets his position average.

Can someone help me with the code?

Thank you so much

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` and compare.

Comment: why did you remove the text tables and replaced them with image ?!!!

Comment: Thanks, but could you please provide a little bit more details? Like how to compare values from 2 different tables based on one column

Comment: I already replace the text tables with images. Please refresh the page

Comment: @SophieFu, what was wrong with that? why did you change to image?

Comment: @SophieFu, always use tags to mention the version of software or server your are using

Answer (score 0):

You can join the information and compare the Performance with Avg

```
select Employee, JobPosition, [Performance Score], [Ave. Performance]
, case 
    when Emp.[Performance Score] >= [Ave. Performance] then 'Meet' 
    else 'Does not meet'
  end AS PerfResult
from Emp
    inner join Perf on Perf.JobPosition = Emp.JobPosition
```